# Looping through all the ACF fields whose key starts with a specific string

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have some custom fields on some posts, and I have assigned some of them keys with unique values: `'field_tab_' . uniqid()`

I would like to loop through all the ACF fields whose key starts with specific string `field_tab_`.

This is what I have so far, but I cannot work it out how to check for a certain string in the key.

```
<?php
$fields = get_field_objects();
if( $fields ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $fields as $field ): ?>
            <li><?php echo $field['label']; ?>: <?php echo $field['value']; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I can use the name instead of the key as well, if that makes it easier.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If `$field[label]` is the key and contains the string `field_tab_` then try this:

```
    <?php
    $fields = get_field_objects();
    if( $fields ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $fields as $field ): ?>
                <?php if(strpos($field[label],'field_tab_') { ?>
                    <li><?php echo $field['label']; ?>: <?php echo $field['value']; ?></li>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.strpos.php

Code is unchecked.